# Convert SQL code to Relational Algebra

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

how would you convert this Select query to relational algebra:

```
SELECT Student.Name, Result.Mark
FROM Student, Results
WHERE Student.ID = Results.ID AND Results.Code = 'G51DBS'
```

This is what I have but I'm not sure:

```
[σ{Student.Name}(Student)]∪[Π{Result.Makr}σ{Student.ID = Results.ID ∧ results.code = g51dbs}(Results)]
```

Comment: Why are you using the Unison sign??

Comment: should it be x instead ?

Comment: Perhaps more suited to [cs.se].

Comment: eggyal sorry i didnt know about this cs website thanks tho !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
∏Name,Mark (σResult.Code="G51DBS"(Student⋈Result))
```

You might want to look at this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/relational_algebra.htm) and for Natural join [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29)

Comment: God damn it I was about to answer ;_;

Comment: what would my answer come up with ? in sql

Comment: It will select column `Name` from `Student` table and `Mark` from `Result` table, who is having `Code='G51DBS'` It will join both table on `ID` column to display rows

Comment: In short it will show marks and name of students for `Code='G51DBS'`